# Publish content

Tags: swift, xcode

I’d like to create an app where I provide the user language courses. Do I need to prepare all courses in advance or is there a tool/platform where I can publish more courses while the app is already online? I wouldn’t want a user to have to update my app every time I want to publish something new.

Comment: You might want to check out Firebase

Comment: Can you give me some more guidance on that? Where in Firebase can I find this option?